# how to create a key value pair from fields in mongodb?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

i have some data structured like this :

```
        "location_identifiers": [
            {
                "permalink": "olivette-missouri",
                "uuid": "e1774b1c-634d-4ea4-1414-cd8be15df631",
                "location_type": "city",
                "entity_def_id": "location",
                "value": "Olivette"
            },
            {
                "permalink": "missouri-united-states",
                "uuid": "51a065b8-05d5-1a28-3fcd-1ad143f1f725",
                "location_type": "region",
                "entity_def_id": "location",
                "value": "Missouri"
            }
```

i want to restructure it to look like this, i am using mongodb compass:

```
"location_identifiers": [
            {
                "city": "Olivette",
                "region": "Missouri"
            }
]
```

i have tried unwind and project query but i am stuck, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {}
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "location_identifiers": [
        {
          "$arrayToObject": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$location_identifiers",
              "as": "item",
              "in": {
                k: "$$item.location_type",
                v: "$$item.value"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A88SJBp5dwy)

Comment: hey @yuting, thanks for the answer, it worked perfectly. i have a follow up question for in a case when field name repeats itself, how do i handle that using arraytoobject. sample json is: [
  {
    "categories": [
      {
        "entity_def_id": "category",
        "permalink": "agriculture",
        "uuid": "6a733ac8-b79c-e2d2-55b9-cc3d66435eb6",
        "value": "Agriculture"
      },
      {
        "entity_def_id": "category",
        "permalink": "food-and-beverage",
        "uuid": "14364faa-63f9-0d45-7b6a-7378113364a2",
        "value": "Food and Beverage"
      }
    ]

Comment: Check this [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9rhKsEvLJb5) . It would be kind of you to accept this answer.